# Show remaining posts in category when clicking button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a loop which shows the first 8 posts for each category of my custom posts using **posts_per_page**.

```
<?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'gallery',
  'category_name' => 'abstract',
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'paged' => $paged);
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- loop contents -->
    <?php the_title(); // etc etc ?>   

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I now need is a button that shows below the loop which says 'See the rest' only if there is more than 8 posts in that category.

When clicked, the rest of the posts in that category are then 'revealed' on the same page...that's it!

Can this be done without AJAX? I feel like it should be fairly straight forward but I'm stuggling to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using js/jQuery for this combined with css **:nth-child**. Firstly I loaded in all the posts for the category rather than limiting it in the loop. Then I used **:nth-child** to essentially 'check' to see if there are more than 8 divs with a class of 'gallery-container' and hide them on page load if so:

```
.gallery-container:nth-child(n+9)
    display: none
```

then when the button is pressed unhide them by using jQuery to add a 'show' class.

```
.show
    display: block !important
```

jQuery:

```
$('.btn-show-more').on('click', function (){
    $('.gallery-container:nth-child(n+9)').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Hope this helps anyone out there struggling with the same issue. I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this, but its working fine for me.